# "Type forwarded to assembly 'Windows version=255.255.255.255'" when trying to use Windows.System.UserProfile

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-assembly, solution

I'm trying to use the `Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen` class from a UWP class library in Visual Studio 2017.

However, trying to reference this class causes a variety of errors regarding a `Windows` assembly reference for version 255.255.255.255. Since 255 is the maximum value for a byte, I'm assuming that's not a real version number.

The error says:

> The type forwarder for 'Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen' in assembly 'Windows' causes a cycle.
>
> The type name 'LockScreen' could not be found in the namespace 'Windows.System.UserProfile'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

[image]

My project structure is:

[image]

My project is configured with minimum Windows 10 version 'November Update (10.0, build 10586)'.

How can I resolve this issue and use the `LockScreen` class?

Comment: What is the target version of the UWP Class Library? Could you right-click the project, go to NuGet and update the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package to the latest stable version?

Comment: @MartinZikmund I tried that, but it made no difference. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm pretty curious how you did this.  You don't have a reference to the contract that allow you to use LockScreen so this should keel over early on a compile error.  What is in the .rd.xml file?  Do you see this error only when building the Release version with .NETNative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this type is actually part of the Desktop Extensions, so you have to add a reference to them in your UWP Class Library. Right-click the project, select **Add**, **Reference...** and in the dialog go to **Universal Windows - Extensions**. There check the box next to **Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP** of the appropriate version the app is targeting.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, this worked. Thanks! For future, is there any easy way to determine which of these extensions a class may reside in?

Comment: Yes! The documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen - you can see a table that says `Windows Desktop Extension SDK (introduced v10.0.10240.0)` - that's the reference

Comment: Glad to help :-). Happy coding

Comment: FYI: you can't just click on an extension and click OK. You must make sure that the checkbox is clicked. It's a terrible interface. This is the third time so far I've attempted to add an extension without actually clicking on the checkbox.